# I can't access to the login screen in Lubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: lubuntu, xorg, 16.04, login-screen

I have a Toshiba NB300 with 1 GB RAM with Intel® Atom™ processor N450 and I recently installed Lubuntu 16.04 LTS i386 and I have this message on the screen instead of the login box

```
/dev/sda6: clean, 124768/2379216 files, 881581/9509376 blocks
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: What you see is just what the PC did before it starts X - the message itself is irrelevant. Your X server doesn't start,  use the console with `cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log > ~/Xorgerror.log` to show the Xorg log and paste it here.

Comment: I didn't see nothing and it show later that message. I can't understand the second part of your message

Comment: Press return to get a login or Alt-F2 to login on the second tty. Use the command from above, paste the contents of Xorgerror.log in your home directory.

Comment: I remember that I can't access to my pc so I can't access to that log :/

Comment: I'm going to go back to Lubuntu 15.04

Comment: No, it's not @ElderGeek

Comment: @antonio8909 Regarding [your response]https://askubuntu.com/questions/761878/i-cant-access-to-the-login-screen-in-lubuntu-16-04-lts?noredirect=1#comment1137648_761878) to the request to paste the conetent of /var/log/Xorg.0.log. Of course you can. Boot from live media, mount the drive (read only if need be) and navigate to `mount location/var/log` Furthermore, I don't see how you can claim this isn't a duplicate of the same question that you asked there and accepted the answer to. Feel free to [edit] your post and convince us it's not identical.

Comment: For @ElderGeek Zanna, Jacob Vlijm, Byte Commander, WinEunuuchs2Unix: In base to what you clicked this as dupplicate? The other is a post made days after this post so this is the original. Anyway the issue was fixed months ago. I don't see why do we need to up this thread.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/help/duplicates

Comment: Forget it. You didn't understand it

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar message with an Asus EEE 900

Rebooted to GRUB and selected "Advanced options for Ubuntu". Selected "recovery mode". Selected "Resume normal boot". Click through the warning about graphics drivers. Boots fine to desktop.

Comment: Did you make a clean install of Lubuntu?